# Reverse Geocoding using HERE maps SDK gives error

Tags: android, here-api

I am trying to retrieve Address for a particular GeoCoordinate using Reverse Geo coding, But I am getting some errors in executing the Reverse GeoCode Request. I am getting Error:400 Bad Request. Here is my full code:

```
public class Address_Service extends AppCompatActivity {
String Location1,Address;
double Lat,Lng;
private ListView list;

private boolean isMapInitialized = false;

//LIST OF ARRAY STRINGS WHICH WILL SERVE AS LIST ITEMS
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();

//DEFINING A STRING ADAPTER WHICH WILL HANDLE THE DATA OF THE LISTVIEW
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


private BroadcastReceiver BUS_COD=new BroadcastReceiver() {  //this receiver recieves new location from Database service
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Location1=intent.getStringExtra("BUS_LOC");

        Lat = Double.valueOf(Location1.substring(0, 9));//extracting latitude
        Lng = Double.valueOf(Location1.substring(10, Location1.length()));//extracting longitude
        Log.e("Got new loc from FB",Location1);
        get_address();
    }
};



 public void get_address()
 {
   ReverseGeocodeRequest2 request = new ReverseGeocodeRequest2(new GeoCoordinate(Lat,Lng,0.0));
  request.execute(new ResultListener<com.here.android.mpa.search.Location>() {
      @Override
      public void onCompleted(com.here.android.mpa.search.Location location, ErrorCode errorCode) {
          if(errorCode!=ErrorCode.NONE){
             Log.e("Error",errocode.getmessage());
          }else{
              if (location != null) {
                  Address = location.getAddress().toString();
                  listItems.add(Address_of_Bus);
              }
          }

      }
  });
}


 @Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reverse_geocode_layout);

    list=(ListView) (findViewById(R.id.listView));

    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    initialize();

}

public void initialize() {
    MapEngine mapEngine= MapEngine.getInstance();
    mapEngine.init(this, new OnEngineInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(Error error) {
            if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {

                IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter();
                intentFilter.addAction("GOT_NEW_L_M");
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(BUS_COD,intentFilter);
                Intent intent=new Intent(Address_Service.this,Database_service.class);
                startService(intent);

                isMapInitialized = true;


            } else {
                Log.e("Initialization", "ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment");
            }
        }
    });

}
  @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(BUS_COD);
    this.stopService(new Intent(Address_Service.this,Database_service.class));
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(BUS_COD);

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("GOT_NEW_L_M");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(BUS_COD,intentFilter);

    super.onResume();
}

}
```

And this is the Logcat with Error:

```
E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5466b490 cert_verify_callback calling    
verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
09-27 17:24:35.352 3554-3770/ 

E/NETWORK: Request:     
https://places.hybrid.api.here.com/places/v1/meta/offline?   
app_id=HxZCZftG2X5aQ0Bhlg1W&app_code=TF3wLtVoLtqhmTi1FOcSaw Error: 400 Bad   
Request
```

I am using this on real device operating at API19.I am actually populating listView with addresses received via Reverse Geocoding.

Here is my layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="430dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you provide exact values for latitude and longitude?

Comment: @ArtemNikitin yes. Lat:19.876442, Lng:75.346828

Comment: @ArtemNikitin I think I should leave this reverse geocoding I will update my app once issue is solved.

Comment: Link with error is not related to geocoding

Comment: @ArtemNikitin Then what is this error actually? Am I making any mistake in program?

Comment: Based on URL, it's related to searching of POIs.

Comment: @ArtemNikitin yes I am searching for POI's address, it is not possible?

Comment: It's possible for sure, but initial question was about geocoding

Comment: @ArtemNikitin so reverse geocoding class cannot be used for this purpose? so how can I get address of POI/a Geocoordinate ?

Comment: It's the exact purpose of geocoding, to find an address by coordinate, but you shouldn't use geocoding for finding something like "Mexican restaurants nearby."

Comment: @ArtemNikitin So how should I pass the geo-coordinate to find address? For example the above geocoordinate? Should I make any change in code?

Comment: @ArtemNikitin I am getting confused, Will you please tell what this issue is and how should I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

HERE provides different product which are covering also specific features and capabilities:

Forward geocoding
Reverse geocoding
Multi-reverse geocoding
Batch geocoding
Geocoding autocomplete
Places (Search)

Please have a look here for an overview: https://developer.here.com/products/geocoding-and-search